# How to check variable type in template toolkit?

Tags: perl, report, reporting

Is there any statement to print variable type in Template Toolkit? This is for debugging purposes.
I was trying to find something like:

```
type(my_var)
```

Output:

```
scalar
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Template::Plugin::Dumper](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Dumper.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PERL directive](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_PERL). Example:

```
[% PERL %]
   print "my_var type: ", ref( $stash->get('my_var') ) || 'scalar';
[% END %]
```